# Posix shell: distinguish between empty and not existing variable

Tags: variables, posix, sh

In pure `/bin/sh` how can I distinguish between an empty variable, an unset variable and a not existing (not defined) variable.

Here are the case:

```
# Case 1: not existing
echo "${foo}"

# Case 2: unset
foo=
echo "${foo}"

# Case 3: Empty
foo=""
echo "${foo}"
```

Now I would like to check for each of those three cases.
If case 2 and case 3 are actually the same, then I must at least be able to distinguish between them and case 1.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Solved thanks to Matteo

Here is how the code looks like:

```
#foo  <-- not defined
bar1=
bar2=""
bar3="a"

if ! set | grep '^foo=' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "foo does not exist"
elif [ -z "${foo}" ]; then
    echo "foo is empty"
else
    echo "foo has a value"
fi

if ! set | grep '^bar1=' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "bar1 does not exist"
elif [ -z "${bar1}" ]; then
    echo "bar1 is empty"
else
    echo "bar1 has a value"
fi

if ! set | grep '^bar2=' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "bar2 does not exist"
elif [ -z "${bar2}" ]; then
    echo "bar2 is empty"
else
    echo "bar2 has a value"
fi


if ! set | grep '^bar3=' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "bar3 does not exist"
elif [ -z "${bar3}" ]; then
    echo "bar3 is empty"
else
    echo "bar3 has a value"
fi
```

And the results:

```
foo does not exist
bar1 is empty
bar2 is empty
bar3 has a value
```

Comment: Your case 2 and case 3 are identical.  `foo=` defines foo to be the empty string exactly the same way that `foo=""` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/set.html)

> If no options or arguments are specified, set shall write the names and values of all shell variables in the collation sequence of the current locale. Each name shall start on a separate line, using the format:

You can list all the variables (`set`) and grep for the variable name you want to check

```
set | grep '^foo='
```

Comment: `function foo=bar { :; }` will fool this in bash, and `bar=$'\nfoo=nope'` will fool it in most other shells.

Comment: It won't if your shell is POSIX compliant.  If you're using `/bin/bash` and not `/bin/sh`, you need to `set -o posix` and it works with caveats.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about `sh`, but in `bash` and `dash` you can do `echo ${TEST:?Error}` for case 1 vs. case 2/3. And from quick glance at [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Variable_Expansion#Substitution_with_a_default_value), it seems like it should work for bourne shell too.

You can use it like this in bash and dash (use $? to get the error code)

```
echo ${TEST:?"Error"}
bash: TEST: Error
[lf@dell:~/tmp/soTest] echo $?
1
[lf@dell:~/tmp/soTest] TEST2="ok"
[lf@dell:~/tmp/soTest] echo ${TEST2:?"Error"}
ok
[lf@dell:~/tmp/soTest] echo $?
0
[lf@dell:~/tmp/soTest] dash
$ echo ${TEST3:?"Error"}       
dash: 1: TEST3: Error
$ TEST3=ok
$ echo ${TEST3:?"Error"}
ok
```

Comment: The syntax is POSIX but it will not distinguish between a non existing variable and an empty variable

Comment: @Matteo I thought of using `$?` to script the cases, see my edit.

Comment: `${TEST:?Error}` does not distinguish between undefined and empty.  `${TEST?Error}` does.

Comment: This will cause a non-interactive shell/script to exit immediately if the variable is unset, you will not be able to check the value of `$?` as you are doing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ${var?} syntax to throw an error if var is unset and ${var:?} to throw an error if var is unset or empty.  For a concrete example:

```
$ unset foo
$ test -z "${foo?unset}" && echo foo is empty || echo foo is set to $foo
-bash: foo: unset
$ foo=
$ test -z "${foo?unset}" && echo foo is empty || echo foo is set to $foo
foo is empty
$ foo=bar
$ test -z "${foo?unset}" && echo foo is empty || echo foo is set to $foo
foo is set to bar
```

For the non-interactive shell, you can use `${+}`.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

check() {
        case ${foo:+set} in
        set) echo foo is set to "'$foo'";;
        *)
                case ${foo+empty} in
                empty) echo foo is empty;;
                *) echo foo is unset;;
                esac
        esac
}

unset foo
check
foo=
check
foo=hello
check
```

Comment: This will cause a non-interactive shell/script to exit immediately upon evaluation of `"${foo?unset}"` if `foo` is unset.

Comment: @tmillr A valid concern.  I've added code to be used in the non-interactive case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a correct answer here yet that is *POSIX compliant*.  First let me reiterate [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)'s assertion that the code `foo=` is indeed setting the variable `foo` to an empty value the same as `foo=""`.  For `foo` to be unset, it must either never be set or unset with `unset foo`.

[Matteo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387981/matteo)'s answer *is* correct, but there are caveats.  When you run `set` in bash and `posix` mode is disabled, it also prints all of the defined functions as well.  This can be suppressed like this:

```sh
isvar() (
    [ -n "$BASH" ] && set -o posix
    set | grep -q "^$1="
)
```

By writing it as a sub-shell function, we don't need to worry about what the state of bash's `posix` setting after we're done.

However, you can still get false-positives from variables whose values contain carriage returns, so understand that this is not 100% foolproof.

```sh
$ a="
> b=2
> "
$ set | grep ^b=
b=2
```

So for maximum correctness you can exploit bash's `-v` test, when available.

```sh
isvar() {
    if [ -n "$BASH" ]; then
        [ -v "$1" ]
    else
        set | grep -q "^$1="
    fi
}
```

Perhaps somebody has a library somewhere that supports other shells' extensions as well.  Essentially, this is a weakness in the POSIX specification and it just hasn't been seen as warranting amendment.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
if ! (: "${foo?}") >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # foo is unset
elif [ "X$foo" '=' 'X' ]; then
    # foo is null/empty
else
    # foo is not null/empty
fi
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell actually knows three variable states:

1. Variable is set to a value.
2. Variable is set but Null.
3. Variable is not set at all (unset).

The most common check used is `-z` but this test actually checks for an empty string after the variable has been expanded. Both, an unset and Null variable expand to an empty string:

```
null=
value="x"
[ -z "$unset" ] && echo '$unset is empty'
[ -z "$empty" ] && echo '$empty is empty'
[ -z "$value" ] && echo '$value is empty'
```

prints

```
$unset is empty
$empty is empty
```

https://onlinegdb.com/gH0L4YywZ

There is no way to directly test a variable being unset but there is Parameter Expansion.

[image: ParameterExpansion]

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

E.g. to check if a variable is set at all, use `+`

```
null=
value="x"
[ -n "${unset+x}" ] && echo '$unset is set'
[ -n "${null+x}" ] && echo '$null is set'
[ -n "${value+x}" ] && echo '$value is set'
```

prints

```
$null is set
$value is set
```

which is the expected result.
https://onlinegdb.com/oPC3i65_We

Note that instead of `+x` you could use anything, also `+IS_SET` if you like. `+...` will result in an empty string if unset and in a string containing `...` in any other case, no matter what `...` is and no matter what non-empty value a variable might have. Thus it will also never conflict with a real value, so `value` also being `x` here is irrelevant.

Also note that there is no such thing as an empty string in POSIX. An empty string is the same as being Null. POSIX variables are always strings, they are only interpreted as integers if you explicitly request that but results of math operations are stored as strings again. That's why `value=""` and `value=` are effectively the same instruction. They create a string with zero characters and that's a Null value in POSIX, as characters are what makes the variable's content and a variable having zero characters has no content, thus it is Null.